# First Character goes to the end of the text when I type in TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox, textchanged

I have a `TextBox`named `PercentageText`. I used `TextChanged` event to Append "%" to text typed inside the `TextBox`. The code inside the `TextChanged` event is given below

```
if (skipTextChange)
                skipTextChange = false;
            else
            {
                skipTextChange = true;
                if (PercentageText.Text =="")
                {
                    PercentageText.Text = " ";
                }

                if (PercentageText.TextLength == 1)
                {
                    if (PercentageText.Text != "%")
                    {
                        PercentageText.Text =""+ PercentageText.Text.Trim() + "%";
                    }
                }
            }
```

and initiallized `SkipTextChange=false;` out side the `TextChanged` Event Block. My Problem is When I Type Anything the first character goes all the way to the end of the text, for an example, if I type 152 it Shows 521 and When I cleared the `TextBox` using keyboard(Back Space key), and Type again it works Perfactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for all this troubles I suggest you to simply add a label to the right of the textbox and put a % as the label's text.

However, if you really want to go for the TextChanged path then you need to test if your input ends with the % char and add it only if not. Also you need to set the position where the next char should be typed.

```
if (skipTextChange)
    skipTextChange = false;
else
{
    skipTextChange = true;
    if (PercentageText.Text == "")
    {
        PercentageText.Text = " ";
    }
    if (!PercentageText.Text.EndsWith("%"))
    {
        PercentageText.Text = "" + PercentageText.Text.Trim() + "%";
        PercentageText.SelectionStart = PercentageText.TextLength - 1;
    }
}
```

Consider to test extensively with this approach. Copy/Paste, Delete and BackSpace behavior should be verified and insertion of multiple spaces or with the case of a  % char typed directly by the user. Of course, if this textbox is supposed to contain only numbers a more complex verification code is required. If this is the context then I suggest to use NUmericUpDown control and the label trick to its right.

Comment: `PercentageText.SelectionStart = PercentageText.TextLength - 1;` what is the purpose of this code?

Comment: It puts the cursor at the exact point where the next character should normally appear.

Comment: Thanks bro... that is what I'm looking for :-)